# when I try to open a new browser window using js in XHTML, the window does not open

Tags: javascript, primefaces, xhtml

I need to display a report in a new window when i click in a dock item, the report is generated but the window does not open.

XHTML code:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="south" size="60">
<p:dock>
    <p:menuitem value=".PDF" icon="/images/dock/pdf.png" 
        action="#{RelatorioPlanoAquisicaoBIDMB.btnGerarRelatorioOnClick()}"
        onclick="this.disabled=true" ajax="false"
        oncomplete= "this.disabled=false; javascript:ResourceNews('relatorios/#{RelatorioPlanoAquisicaoBIDMB.chaveArquivo}-relatorio_plano_aquisicao.pdf','750','550','no')"
        update="growl" />
    <p:menuitem value="Sair" icon="/images/dock/sair.png"
        action="#{RelatorioPlanoAquisicaoBIDMB.btnSairOnClick()}"
        onclick="this.disabled=true" />
</p:dock>        
<p:ajaxStatus style="margin:15px;margin-right:25px;margin-bottom:0px; text-align:right">                 
    <f:facet name="start">
        <p:graphicImage value="../images/gifs/ajax-loader2.gif" />
    </f:facet>
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

JavasCript code:

```
function ResourceNews(url, l, a, s){
    var x = parseInt((screen.width-l)/2);
    var y = parseInt((screen.height-a)/2);
    var win = window.open(url,'','width='+l+',height='+a+',scrollbars='+s);
    win.moveTo(x,y);
}
```

The method that opens a new window has to be invoked in "onComplete", because the window has to open only when the report is ready. But it doesn't open, it opens only if is in "onclick", but in this case the system doesn't find the .pdf because it hasn't finished being generated.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: And how would the `oncomplete` event fire when you click something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) says, `oncomplete` is a handler to execute when ajax request is completed.
You've specified `ajax="false"`. That's why the handler doesn't get invoked - there is no ajax request, just a normal POST.

Another problem is that the `#{RelatorioPlanoAquisicaoBIDMB.chaveArquivo}` value is not known prior to clicking the menuitem. This could be fixed by using `org.primefaces.context.RequestContext` to render the js function call in the action method.

```
public void btnGerarRelatorioOnClick() {
     /* ... */
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ResourceNews('relatorios/" + getChaveArquivo() +
        "-relatorio_plano_aquisicao.pdf','750','550','no');"
```

Comment: but if `ajax= "true"`, `#{RelatorioPlanoAquisicaoBIDMB.chaveArquivo}` will return a not update data, then the browser won't find the archive. `#{RelatorioPlanoAquisicaoBIDMB.btnGerarRelatorioOnClick()}` generate a new value for `chaveArquivo`

Comment: @henrique, I expanded the answer.

Comment: well, `RequestContext.execute()` not works, because of an incompatibility between a static and non-static method, but i turn the main problem around by generate the value of `chaveArquivo` before click the menuitem

Comment: @henrique, fixed it, forgot the `getCurrentInstance()`.